# Extracting 5 bands geotiff file into RGB file using GDAL?

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, multi-band

I have a five bands geotiff file for Red, Green, Blue, Red-edge and Infra-red, and want to use `gdal_translate` to extract bands Red, Green and Blue

```
gdal_translate -b 1 -b 2 -b 3 -mask "none" "input.tif" "output.tif"
```

However, the generated file has the wrong colours (most of pointozs are blacks).

I guess it is related with colour range and ColorInterp is undefined. But I don't know how to fix them.

This is the gdalinfo for the original  file:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: input.tif
Size is 10458, 10825
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 56S",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",153],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",10000000],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","32756"]]
Origin = (411260.815060000050000,6878637.363170000700000)
Pixel Size = (0.012419999999981,-0.012419999999981)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  TIFFTAG_SOFTWARE=MicaSense
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=DEFLATE
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  411260.815, 6878637.363) (152d 5'44.47"E, 28d12'54.39"S)
Lower Left  (  411260.815, 6878502.917) (152d 5'44.44"E, 28d12'58.76"S)
Upper Right (  411390.703, 6878637.363) (152d 5'49.24"E, 28d12'54.43"S)
Lower Right (  411390.703, 6878502.917) (152d 5'49.20"E, 28d12'58.79"S)
Center      (  411325.759, 6878570.140) (152d 5'46.84"E, 28d12'56.59"S)
Band 1 Block=10458x1 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Gray
  Min=0.000 Max=5454.000 
  Minimum=0.000, Maximum=5454.000, Mean=1036.637, StdDev=1083.467
  NoData Value=0
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=5454
    STATISTICS_MEAN=1036.637087124
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=1083.4669493555
Band 2 Block=10458x1 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Undefined
  Min=0.000 Max=6616.000 
  Minimum=0.000, Maximum=6616.000, Mean=1332.553, StdDev=1386.218
  NoData Value=0
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=6616
    STATISTICS_MEAN=1332.553257019
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=1386.2184173683
Band 3 Block=10458x1 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Undefined
  Min=0.000 Max=8943.000 
  Minimum=0.000, Maximum=8943.000, Mean=1594.110, StdDev=1699.603
  NoData Value=0
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=8943
    STATISTICS_MEAN=1594.1095702538
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=1699.603238969
Band 4 Block=10458x1 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Undefined
  Min=0.000 Max=9650.000 
  Minimum=0.000, Maximum=9650.000, Mean=1924.547, StdDev=2032.229
  NoData Value=0
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=9650
    STATISTICS_MEAN=1924.5465918094
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=2032.228987124
Band 5 Block=10458x1 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Undefined
  Min=0.000 Max=16783.000 
  Minimum=0.000, Maximum=16783.000, Mean=2732.010, StdDev=2919.037
  NoData Value=0
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=16783
    STATISTICS_MEAN=2732.0096822665
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=2919.0373612217
```

This is the gdalinfo for output file:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: output.tif
Size is 10458, 10825
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 56S",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",153],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",10000000],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","32756"]]
Origin = (411260.815060000050000,6878637.363170000700000)
Pixel Size = (0.012419999999981,-0.012419999999981)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  TIFFTAG_SOFTWARE=MicaSense
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  411260.815, 6878637.363) (152d 5'44.47"E, 28d12'54.39"S)
Lower Left  (  411260.815, 6878502.917) (152d 5'44.44"E, 28d12'58.76"S)
Upper Right (  411390.703, 6878637.363) (152d 5'49.24"E, 28d12'54.43"S)
Lower Right (  411390.703, 6878502.917) (152d 5'49.20"E, 28d12'58.79"S)
Center      (  411325.759, 6878570.140) (152d 5'46.84"E, 28d12'56.59"S)
Band 1 Block=10458x1 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Gray
  Min=0.000 Max=5454.000 
  Minimum=0.000, Maximum=5454.000, Mean=1036.637, StdDev=1083.467
  NoData Value=0
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=5454
    STATISTICS_MEAN=1036.637087124
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=1083.4669493555
Band 2 Block=10458x1 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Undefined
  Min=0.000 Max=6616.000 
  Minimum=0.000, Maximum=6616.000, Mean=1332.553, StdDev=1386.218
  NoData Value=0
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=6616
    STATISTICS_MEAN=1332.553257019
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=1386.2184173683
Band 3 Block=10458x1 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Undefined
  Min=0.000 Max=8943.000 
  Minimum=0.000, Maximum=8943.000, Mean=1594.110, StdDev=1699.603
  NoData Value=0
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=8943
    STATISTICS_MEAN=1594.1095702538
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=1699.603238969
```

Comment: Hi Bangyou, I see you are processing MicaSense data using GDAL. I'm trying to do the same. Could we talk about it, outside this forum?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your values aren't in 0,255 since they are UInt16. You can try rescaling to 0,255 (GDAL works it out by default from input min/max and output default 0,255):

```
gdal_translate -b 1 -b 2 -b 3 -mask "none" "input.tif" "output.tif" -scale
```

Note you can add params if the defaults aren't sensible:

```
-scale [src_min src_max [dst_min dst_max]]
```

http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html

Note that you obviously will lose some information at this lower colour depth, and it may be better to simply use a different program for viewing, that doesn't assume 8-bit RGB.

Comment: I have the same problem, I guess QGIS and ArcGIS all assume 8-bit RGB.  What software can viewing?